# Rope breaks using Revolute joints

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

i am working on rope physics. i have implemented one rope using Revolute joints ..

I'm making rope connecting dynamic bodies (via b2RevoluteJoints).i successfully created it.Now i also attach one dynamic body at the end of rope . & i m releasing my this rope with this body downwards , now somehow my joints between my dynamic rope bodies are stretched & then breaks ,  I want my rope looks smoother.

my joints are like this

```
b2RevoluteJointDef revoluteJointDef;
revoluteJointDef.bodyA = referenceBody;//provided by testbed
revoluteJointDef.bodyB = lastLink;
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA = startPos;//world coords, because m_groundBody is at (0,0)
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set(0,0);//center of circle
world->CreateJoint( &revoluteJointDef );


revoluteJointDef.bodyA = lastLink;//the last added link of the chain
revoluteJointDef.bodyB = chainBase;
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorA.Set(0,linkWidth);//the regular position for chain link joints
revoluteJointDef.localAnchorB.Set(0,linkWidth);//a little in from the edge of the circle
world->CreateJoint( &revoluteJointDef );
```

Is there any way to make strong joints ??

can we achieve this by working on Density of bodies & gravity of world ??

please help .....

Comment: Roughly, how many revolute joints are there?

Comment: hmmmm around 30 Revolute joints in a single rope  & 2 ropes r there .. both of rope has one end at groundbody (upper edge of grond ) & other end attached with one dynamic b2body hanging in world.

Comment: How dense and how big are the bodies on the end of the ropes?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (but with the centrifugal force of swinging a larger object at the end of the rope). To solve the problem of the breaking chain/rope you need to make the larger object less dense, but this then introduces a knock on problem - now your "larger" dynamic object gets held correctly by the rope but does not interact with the rest of the world as it should.

To solve this problem I did something a bit hacky and implemented my own collision handler which would apply a collision impulse to the thing that my larger object collided with as if it were heavier. So...

- make your object at the end of the rope very low density so that the rope holds
- implement some supplemental collision handlers for your object to make it seem like your object is more dense to other objects (sensor = true may help with this as well).

It is not strictly in the spirit of the physics simulator, as we should be able to set our parameters and let the rules take care of everything - basically it would be nice if the revolute joints were unbreakable.